# Jquery to change a form's target

Tags: jquery, html, forms, target

I want to change the form's target based on the option which is selected.

```
<form id='post_form' target="targetvalue">

<select id="select" name="select">
<option value="option1">Option 1</option>
<option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>

    </form>


 <script>
 $("#select").change(function() {
    var targetvalue = $("#select option:selected").text();
    $("#post_form").attr("target", targetvalue);
    });

 </script>
```

Comment: What version of jquery do you use?

Comment: And what is your question? So far you stated the truth, which is nice, but not at all leading to anything.

Comment: I have this in my header:
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

My question is why isnt it working?

Comment: @Martijn, does it "work" better if you put the code in a `ready` handler?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. If you want to set the `target` to either `Option 1` or `Option 2`, what you have is correct. However, if you want to set the target to either `option1` or `option2`, you should have:

   ```
   var targetvalue = $("#select option:selected").val();
   ```

   which can be simplified to just;

   ```
   var targetvalue = $(this).val();
   ```
2. If you're using jQuery > 1.6, you should be using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead of [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr). For more details see StackOverflow: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

   ```
   $("#select").change(function() {
       var targetvalue = /* which ever you decide */;
       $("#post_form").prop("target", targetvalue);
   });
   ```
3. You shouldn't really be linking to just the *latest* version in a production environment; if a new version of jQuery gets released with breaking changes, you're screwed. Link to a specific version of jQuery, and test thoroughly before you upgrade to a new release;

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   ```
4. If you're *only* defining the `<script>` after the `<form>` element to be able to target it, realise you can use a `$(document).ready()` block to define the script anywhere;

   ```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#select').change(function () {
               var targetvalue = /* which ever you decide */;
               $('#post_form').prop("target", targetvalue);
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If indeed your HTML page is written as is specified in the question then the script will run after the DOM has been updated with the form you are trying to modify - but if the script is part of a JavaScript file linked in the  then you need to enclose it within the $(document).ready() function ....

Thanks @T.J.Crowder for linking the following article on this -> [Document ready event ?](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)

Place your script within the $(document).ready() block - this will ensure the DOM is ready before attemptig to change it :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#select").change(function() {
       var targetvalue = $(this).val();
       $("#post_form").prop("target", targetvalue);
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If things are as shown in the question, there's no need. As long as the `script` block is *below* the `select` box in the document source, the `select` box will be there and accessible even before jQuery's `ready` event fires. See [this message on the subject](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41) from the Google's Closure library engineers.